# Share wishlist using Graphql mutation

Tags: magento2.4, wishlist, graphql, share-wishlist

I need to share wishlist using Graphql in Magento2.4.

Anyone could assist me in this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create module SharingWishlist sequence Magento_WishlistGraphQl
2. Define schema in etc/schema.graphqls

```
type Query {
    sharingWishlist(sharing_code: String!) : Wishlist! @resolver(class: "Vendor\\SharingWishlist\\Model\\Resolver\\SharingWishlist")
}
```

3. Create resolver Vendor\SharingWishlist\Model\Resolver\SharingWishlist

```
<?php

/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\SharingWishlist\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory;

/**
* Resolver for Item
*/
class SharingWishlist implements ResolverInterface
{
   /**
    * @var WishlistFactory
    */
   protected WishlistFactory $wishlistFactory;

   /**
    * SharingWishlist constructor.
    * @param WishlistFactory $wishlistFactory
    */
   public function __construct(
       WishlistFactory $wishlistFactory
   )
   {
       $this->wishlistFactory = $wishlistFactory;
   }

   /**
    * @inheritdoc
    */
   public function resolve(
       Field $field,
       $context,
       ResolveInfo $info,
       array $value = null,
       array $args = null
   )
   {
       if (!isset($args['sharing_code'])) {
           throw new LocalizedException(__('Missing key "code" in Wishlist value data'));
       }

       $code = $args['sharing_code'];

       $wishlistFactoryCreate = $this->wishlistFactory->create();

       $wishlist = $wishlistFactoryCreate->loadByCode($code);

       $wishlist->setId($wishlist->getOrigData('wishlist_id'));

       return [
           'id' => (string)$wishlist->getId(),
           'sharing_code' => $wishlist->getSharingCode(),
           'updated_at' => $wishlist->getUpdatedAt(),
           'items_count' => $wishlist->getItemsCount(),
           'model' => $wishlist
       ];
   }
}
```

- That's all you can get wishlist by graphql

```
  query sharingWishlist($sharing_code: String = "FrywWTpFihhWMHgO9u4dmUezfMStIFMm"){
    sharingWishlist(sharing_code: $sharing_code) {
      items_count
      sharing_code
      updated_at
      items_v2 {
        items {
          id
          quantity
          description
          added_at
          product {
          __typename
          uid
          sku
          name
          ... on SimpleProduct {
            image {
              url
              label
            }
            image_hover
          }
          special_from_date
          special_to_date
          created_at
          rating_summary
          stock_status
          categories{
            uid
          }
          only_x_left_in_stock
          thumbnail {
            url
            position
            disabled
            label
          }
          url_key
          url_rewrites {
            url
          }
          price_range {
            maximum_price {
              final_price {
                currency
                value
              }
              regular_price {
                currency
                value
              }
            }
            minimum_price {
              final_price {
                currency
                value
              }
              regular_price {
                currency
                value
              }
            }
          }
          ... on ConfigurableProduct {
            variants {
              product {
                color
                size
                image_hover
                image {
                  url
                  label
                }
                uid
                sku
              }
            }
            configurable_options {
              id
              uid
              attribute_id
              attribute_id_v2
              attribute_uid
              attribute_code
              label
              position
              use_default
              values {
                value_index
                uid
                label
                default_label
                store_label
                use_default_value
                swatch_data {
                  value
                }
              }
              product_id
            }
          }
          ... on GroupedProduct {
            items {
              product {
                sku
              }
            }
          }
        }
          ... on ConfigurableWishlistItem {
            configurable_options {
              configurable_product_option_uid
              configurable_product_option_value_uid
            }
          }
        }
        page_info {
          page_size
          current_page
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

For frontent I was create a route like /customer/:sharing_code
Then I get sharing_code param and send graphQl request
In case vuestorefront

```
        const graphqlQuery = {
          "operationName": "loadShareWishlist",
          "query": loadShareWishlist,
          "variables": {
            ...route.value.params
          }
        };

        const sharingWishlistData = (await $vsf.$magento.client.post($vsf.$magento.config.magentoApiEndpoint, graphqlQuery)).data;

        const {sharingWishlist} = sharingWishlistData.data;

        wishlist.value = sharingWishlist as Wishlist | Object;
```

So you need just make a button to copy link like customer/: sharing_code